Why Nginx cannot send the request to the backend?
Situation: I can acccess the http://10.32.19.107:8080/success page using Spring Boot, and I wrote a default.conf for Nginx like this:
location /test/ {
        proxy_pass http://10.32.19.107:8080/success;
    }

Then I restart the Nginx container which is in docker. I entered http://10.32.19.107/test but got a 404.
Here is my whole Nginx default.conf:
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  10.32.19.107;

    # 首页
    index index.html;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /test/ {
        proxy_pass http://10.32.19.107:8080/success;
    }

    location /api/ {
        auth_request /auth;
        
        proxy_pass http://10.32.19.107:8080/success;
    }

    location = /auth {
        
        internal;
        
        set $query '';
        if ($request_uri ~* "[^\?]+\?(.*)$") {
            set $query $1;
        }
        
        proxy_pass http://10.32.19.107:8080/verify?$query;
        
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        
        proxy_set_header Content-Type "";
     }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {

        }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
     }

}

Task: I want to access the same page as http://10.32.19.107:8080/success when I entered http://10.32.19.107/test.
Action: I deleted the Nginx container and map the conf, html, logs, ssl, nginx.conf, conf.d, default.conf to the same file/directory in Nginx and reinstall the container. Here is my command:
sudo docker run --name Nginx -p 80:80 

-v /home/jpdeng/projects/openai-microservice/dev-ops/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx  \

-v /home/jpdeng/projects/openai-microservice/dev-ops/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html \

-v /home/jpdeng/projects/openai-microservice/dev-ops/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \

-v /home/jpdeng/projects/openai-microservice/dev-ops/nginx/conf/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d \

-v /home/jpdeng/projects/openai-microservice/dev-ops/nginx/conf/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \

-v /home/jpdeng/projects/openai-microservice/dev-ops/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl/  \--privileged=true -d --restart=always nginx

Result: still 404 and I don't know why.

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}


do I miss some details or information? Any suggestion will be appreciated!

HAHA! I FIXED THE PROBLEM! It's because the configuration of the firewall. Just use the command, and it can work:
sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp

Now I am a problem solver! The first problem I solve in StackOverflow!

Thank ChatGPT for inspring me! And thank the bros who helped me when I was desperated.

Try this:
    location = /test {
        proxy_pass http://10.32.19.107:8080/success;
    }


Still 404 bro. And I do the test because the auth doesn't work with http://10.32.19.107/api/?token=success (But I can access the http://10.32.19.107:8080/verify?token=success) and I found that even if without the auth, I can not access the success page.

What is the result you have when access /verify?token=success? Is that the index page? And how about using /test/ instead of /test?

That's a message:  test success by Julius Caesar , from:
@GetMapping("/success")
public String success(){
return "test success by Julius Caesar";
}

Have you tried /test/ (instead of /test)? Is it 404?

It's a Whitelabel Error Page:
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Apr 12 01:56:05 CST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Please check target url first, does it also return 404?

It's a "Welcome to nginx!" when I enter 10.32.19.107

It wait for a long time when I enter 10.32.19.107/test, not imediately 404

I guess the 404 response is come from you springboot application, nginx just forwarded to you? try access springboot directly in browser and see what happened: http://10.32.19.107:8080/success

It's test success by Julius Caesar, bro, I think springboot works and nginx doesn't because of this

Is the config file you place is default config? How about the nginx.conf?

let me see the file

if the 404 response contains message like Whitelabel Error Page, it's absolute come from springboot right?

Also, could you please show the tree structure of your Spring project? Does it have the index.html file?

I'm sorry Alex, I didn't get it, do you mean Whitelabel Error Page is a signal that the error comes from springboot?

Mr  phuc16102001, I updated my question and put my >nginx.conf in the quesion. Thanks bro!

location = /test {
proxy_pass http://10.32.19.107:8080/success;
}
I enter http://10.32.19.107/test/, 404;

God, I didn't thought it's a so difficult problem, it's really weird

Alex, do you mean that it's my springboot that cannot receive the request from nginx? It's really a new perspective! Let my have a try, thanks!

yes, if 404 response body or title contains Whitelabel Error Page, that produced by spring, because nginx's 404 should be different from what spring produces. also, you can check the nginx error log, which location in your config is error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

I really can't believe it because the error.log is 0 byte!

You can also check access.log, also, if nginx is configured correctly (= /test) and you type it correctly in your browser (/test, no extra slashes at the end), it should proxy /success page normally, if it still doesn't work, Then I have no way of guessing what the problem is.

Thank you bro, I appreciate so much that you help me so much! Wish you all the best!

Also, please try to copy the config to nginx.conf file :think:

do you mean copy the
location = /test {
proxy_pass http://10.32.19.107:8080/success;
}
to the nginx.conf?
or the whole server{}?
